# jQuery rebind off on when loaded via ajax

Tags: jquery, extend

I want to provide an extension for jQuery so that I re-bind the event handlers.  This is because the event handlers are bound when a partial view is loaded using ajax and they are bound to `$(document)` so that they fire on the page.

However if the page is not refreshed when the partial is downloaded once more I now get two events bound.  And so on.

Hence I created an extension that will unbind the previous event and re-add it.

**Is this a plausible solution?**

```
jQuery.fn.extend({

    offOn: function (types, selector, data, fn) {
        this.off(types, selector, fn);
        this.on(types, selector, data, fn);
    }

});
```

Used like so within a partial that is loaded via a click event on my main page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


$(function() {
    $(document).offOn('click', '#my-details-section  a.delete-row', onDeleteRow);

    function onDeleteRow() { // do something }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Yes, it's plausible though it's so simple a plugin is hardly necessary. Also, the `.off()` call could be safely simplified by namespacing the event, eg. `$(document).off('click.partialLoad').on('click.partialLoad', '#my-details-section  a.delete-row', onDeleteRow);`.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot I'm not sure I completely understand what you mean by namespacing the event sorry?

Comment: `click.partialLoad` namespaces the event as in my example. It allows `.off()` to selectively detach handler(s) previously attached with `.on()` using the same namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at creating a plugin.  It's really quite easy.  Here's some documentation to get you started: [Creating a jQuery Plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

This will allow you to reuse it with much more ease.